# Importance of static object in a class and how they are different from general object

Tags: c++, object, static

```
#include "B.h"

class A
{
    public :
        A()
        {
            s_b = new B();
            b = new B();
        }

       static B *s_b;

        B *b;
};



#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    cout<<"hello";
}
```

In my project I have seen static object as above. But not able to know what is the exact use of it and how they are different from general object.
Please help me in finding out what I can do with s_b which is not being done by b.

Comment: Your code does not even compile.

Comment: You don't need `new` there.

Comment: @Gorpik:This is just a pseudo code .

Comment: even if s_b was a pointer - initializing it with a new B every time A is created? A memory leak?

Answer (score 3):

For one, `s_b` doesn't take up memory for each instance of `A` that is created, whereas `b` does. The `sizeof(A)` is increased by `b`, but not by `s_b`.

A `static` is shared between all instances of the class, so it acts like a global. You don't need an object to access it, you can use `A::s_b` directly.

Answer (score 2):

The only real difference between a static member and an object or function defined at namespace scope is access.  A static data member can be private, for example, in which case it cannot be accessed outside of the class; and a static function member can access private data members, which a function at namespace scope cannot.

The access syntax is also different: if outside the class, you must use `ClassName::memberName` (or `classInstance.memberName`) to access the member.  There is no `using` which can make it accessable otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking static members have to be initialized outside the declaration of the class except for constant int type if you are not using C++11.

So your code posted above is flawed. you need a statement like

```
    A::s_b = B();
```

outside the class A { ... }; To initialize an static member inside an non static constructor is wrong because the constructor is used to construct an object but the static member 
 does not belong to the object but belong to the class. So these static members can not be modified through static member functions.

Think "class" as "human being" and an object of that "class" as a specific person, like "John Smith". So if you have a field, "salary". That should be a non-static field since each person has a different salary. But if you have field, "total_population", which should be a static member because this field semantically does not belong to one specific person but to the whole "human being".

Comment: Ya i got it . i have to initialize s_b as follows inside cpp file 
B * A::s_b = NULL ;
Can you please explain what is the need of this static object ?

Comment: Well you wrote the class A, we didn't. How can we tell what it's for? Every instance of A has its own b. However they all share the same s_b.

Comment: Is it ok to delete this static object inside the destructor ?
since many objects might share this static object but the static object will share one common memory . So when the drestructor is being called for lots of time the static object is going to be deleted for many times which leads to assertion error .Please make me correct if i am wrong .

Comment: As I said in my answer, the static member belongs to the "class", not the object. So if you have something, for example, you want to count how many objects of this class have been created, you need a static member to record that count. So if semantically, a member belongs to the object, for example, if you want a unique name for each object you created, then that member should not be static.  Yes you should delete the static member from your destructor. Generally speaking, you manipulate your static members/fields via static member functions.

Comment: @JohnSmith::+1 for stating the right way to use static members .